# Work around for catching NullPointerException Java

Tags: android, json, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to parse a JSON but also allowing the user to input part of the JSON url. As a result there will be instances when the url "looks" correct but points to nothing. This causes a NullPointerException. In order to stop my code crashing I've had to catch this error. I know you aren't really supposed to do this so can anyone tell me a better way to solve the issue? Apologies as I'm quite new to Java/Android.

```js
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


            try {
                String url_select = Final;

                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_select,
                        "GET", param);
                 


                articles = json.getJSONObject("primaryTopic");
                regadress = articles.getJSONObject("RegAddress");
                try{
                    town = regadress.getString("PostTown");
                }

                catch (JSONException e2){
                    Log.e("JSONException", e2.toString());
                    town = regadress.getString("AddressLine2");
                }
                title = articles.getString("CompanyName");
                description = articles.getString("CompanyStatus");


            }
            catch (java.lang.NullPointerException e) {
                Log.e("NullPointerException", e.toString());
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //showButtonDialog();
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
                Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
                e3.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (JSONException e5) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //showButtonDialog();
                Log.e("JSONException", e5.toString());
                e5.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            try {

                String newTitle = Html.fromHtml(title).toString();
                txtTitle.setText(newTitle);
                String newDesc = Html.fromHtml(description).toString();
                txtDesc.setText(newDesc);
                String newTown = Html.fromHtml(town).toString();
                txtTown.setText(newTown);

                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());

            }
        }
```

Comment: and what's wrong with catching exceptions? its pretty standard thing to do.

Comment: Well I'd seen some others say catching this particular exception shouldn't be done. Then again their usual reasoning is that it could cause something to go wrong later on in the code, which in my case is unlikely as catching the exception stops the code and requires the url be re-entered...

Comment: Which line is causing the NPE?

Comment: Look into [JSONObject.has()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#has%28java.lang.String%29) and [isNull()](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#isNull%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: articles = json.getJSONObject("primaryTopic"); i think, which is strange because it's not being stopped by the JSONException

Comment: Mm tried an if loop with if(json.getJSONObject("primaryTopic")isNull) but didnt stop the NPE

Comment: You'd use `if ( json.has("primaryTopic") && !json.isNull("primaryTopic") ) {...`.

Comment: You're coding for Android, I presume?

Comment: Yes I am. Alright I'll give that a go

Comment: What's the type of `jParser`? - What does `makeHttpRequest` return when a URL "points to nothing"? Where is the error handling for the HTTP &c performed?

Comment: I just found a `JSONParser` at http://techlovejump.com/android-json-parser-from-url/. This one basically just ignores all exceptions and returns `null` upon error.

Comment: hmm that might help I'll try it. I'm not sure what it returns, seems like a try{} catch{} method inside the JSONParser class

Comment: Still no luck. Might have to just stick with this questionable method....